# JS HTML: Get particular column value after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a table with several columns. Each row has an edit button.

[image]

If the user clicks on it, a modal view opens. The user can enter some values and send these via AJAX to my controller.

[image]

My problem is that I have no idea how to transfer to my JS function which particular edit button the user has actually clicked in the table.

*In the past I had an edit button in each row:*

```
  <td><a th:href="'/edit/' + *{person.getName()}" class="btn-sm btn-success"
                           role="button">Edit</a></td>
```

But this led me to a new HTML view where the user could edit. With my new UI I want really only to go with the modal.

But since JS/AJAX has no idea about the whole table it seems to me like a totally wrong approach to me. Moreover I am pretty new to JS/AJAX

Currently I call the JS function like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        id="subscribe-email-form" onclick="updateModal()">Save
                </button>
```

**What can solve my Problem?:**

If I could just give a parameter to `updateModal` it would work but since I call the modal view with `id="myModal"` by the edit button with `data-target="#myModal"` I cannot transfer any id.

Here is my JS and what I want is to find the correct parameter for the field `oldID`

Thank you a lot in advance!

```
function updateModal() {
    var newValues = {};
    newValues["newName"] = $("#newName").val();
    newValues["newAge"] = $("#newAge").val();
    newValues["newID"] = $("#newID").val();
    var oldID = "???";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/api/edit/oldID",
        data: JSON.stringify(newValues),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display("SUCCESS");
            resultObj = data.result;
            updateContent(resultObj[0].phone);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display("ERROR");
            //display(2);
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            display("DONE");
            enableSearchButton(true);
        }
    });
}
```

and the relevant HTML part

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h3>Overview</h3>
    <br>

    <div class="container" id="modal-submit">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Age</th>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
                <tr id="person" th:each="person : ${elementList}">

                    <td th:text="${person.getName()}" id="username"></td>
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTradableBTC" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                    <td th:text="${person.getAge()}" th:id="${person.getName()+person.getAge()}" id="age"></td>
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTop" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                    <td th:text="${person.getId()} " th:id="${person.getName()+person.getId()}" id="userID"></td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal">
                                    Edit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="delete">Delete
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addElement">Add Element</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" id="DeleteAll">Delete all Elements</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Change data</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input name="referencia" id="newName" type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Enter new name">
                        <br>
                        <input name="referencia" id="newAge" type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Enter new age">
                        <br>
                        <input name="referencia" id="newID" type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Enter new id">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Discard
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        id="subscribe-email-form" onclick="updateModal()">Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<br>
```

Comment: How `<td th:text="${person.getId()} " th:id="${person.getName()+person.getId()}" id="userID"></td>` looks like on html?? .. *I mean how it looks like on the browser inspect elements > elements*

Comment: <td id="Anna14.0">14.0</td>

Comment: Why not just use localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** `id=` must be unique so don't duplicate ids .. `person1` , `age1` , `userID1` for the next person 1 will be 2 and so on.. you can also use `class=` instead of `id=`

**2nd:** If change it to classes .. on edit button click you can use

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.userID').text());
```

You can then pass the userID to the `modal` and get it again when saveEdit

> **Note:** This code'll work if you change `id="person"` to `class="person"` same thing with `age` and `userID`

Again and Again **Don't use same id for more than one element** .. delete button has duplicated id .. so you need to change it as well .. and after change `id="delete"` to `class="delete"` you can then use

```
$('.delete').on('click' , function(){
   // do ajax things for remove then
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**If you append the rows dynamically you'll need to use**

```
$(document).on( 'click' , '.delete' , function(){ /* code here */ }); // use same way with dynamically created element events
```